# Why i am not getting No unique bean of type in Autowiring in spring

Tags: java, spring

Person.java

```
@Controller
public class Person 
{
    @Autowired
    private Ability ability;

     public void printMessage(){

         ability.printMessasge();
     }

     public void setOutputGenerator( Ability ability) {
            this.ability = ability;
        }  
}
```

Ability.java

```
@Controller
public class Ability 
{
     void printMessasge(){

         System.out.println("I print message");
     }

}
```

spring.xml

```
<bean id="invisible" class="com.mkyong.common.Ability" >
</bean>  

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong" />
```

App.java

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring.xml");

        Person person = (Person) context.getBean("person");
        person.printMessage( );
    }
```

In the above example i have defined two beans of `Ability` class one using `@Controller` and one in `xml` file. According to `Autowire` by type i should get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
...
No unique bean of type [com.mkyong.common.Ability] is defined:
```

But i am getting proper output. Why?

And if i create an interface which Ability class implements then i would get UnsatisfiedDependencyException exception. Like this:

Parent.java

```
public interface Parent{

     public void printMessasge();

}
```

Ability.java

```
@Controller
public class Ability implements Parent
{
      void printMessasge(){

         System.out.println("I print message");
     }
```

Person.java

```
@Controller
public class Person 
{
    @Autowired
    Parent parent;
     public void printMessage(){
         parent.printMessasge();
     }

     public void setOutputGenerator( Parent parent) {
            this.parent= parent;
        }  
}
```

Comment: you have SpringBeans.xml, but in example it called spring.xml

Comment: @ServerSideCat corrected

Comment: what if you make your bean called not "invisible" but "ability" ?

Comment: @ServerSideCat then both will have same bean id ,which will result into single bean in application

Comment: `Ability` should be `interface`. So, when you initialize the implementation of Ability interface in xml, it will be autowired in `Person ` class

Comment: User `@Qaulifier` annotation give the name 'invisible'.

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal i dont want to use i just want the exception because there are two beans of same class

Answer (score 3):

By default Spring indeed matches by type, but in case of multiple matching beans, it falls back to matching by name. The reference ([*6.9.4 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)) says:

> For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier value.

Using the [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation makes the autowiring by type and additionally by name more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to get a `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` with this configuration because Spring is smart enough to also look at the name of your required dependency, as @Adam writes in his answer. So even if the default autowiring mode is *by type* and there are two beans of the same type for that dependency, Spring is able to solve the conflict.

This behavior is described in the official documentation, [6.9.4 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) section.
More details about autowiring modes can be found [6.4.5 Autowiring collaborators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire).

**If you change the name of Person.ability field to something else, like Person.ability2, then Spring will throw a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`**. It cannot decide which bean it should wire for the Person.ability2 field because:

1. There are two beans of `com.mkyong.common.Ability` type in the context
2. Field name does not match with either bean names

EDIT: in the second case you mention (with the interface), Spring throws the exception for the same bean naming reason I explained above.

---

Official documentation references:

- [6.4.5 Autowiring collaborators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-autowire)
- [6.9.4 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: Good job providing additional explanations

Answer (score 0):

you have two ambiguous beans defined, when spring try find the bean via type it finds two beans, one via scan other explicitly defined in spring.xml. use @Qualifier to mark the correct bean loaded in Person class. So probably you want like this,

```
 @Controller
public class Person 
{

      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("invisible")
      private Ability ability;

     public void printMessage(){

         ability.printMessasge();
     }

     public void setOutputGenerator( Ability ability) {
            this.ability = ability;
        }  
}
```